# How to manually download Vaadin versions for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, vaadin, ivy

I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 and installed the Ivy plugin and Vaadin plugin from the market place as instructed by their book, but I'm unable to create a project since every time I try to I get the message:

> Failed to list downloaded Vaadin versions

From what I'm reading around, Vaadin uses Ivy for managing the download of their packages but it seems to be blocked by my company's firewall.

Since the available versions cannot be downloaded, the combobox for selecting the version comes empty, stopping the process to create the project.

Is there a way to download the Vaadin version I need separately? Are there any options for me in my situation?

Comment: You could also consider setting up a Nexus or Artifactory server within your firewall for use by Java builds. Such a server would also improve performance as it would cache remote content locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the [Vaadin download page](https://vaadin.com/download) and select the *Download as .zip* option on the left of the page as in the image below. Please note that only the visual editor plugin is IDE dependent, while Vaadin as a framework can be used regardless of the IDE (you could write your code in notepad and compile it with the jars in the classpath), so there's no such thing as *Vaadin versions for Eclipse*.

[image: Vaadin downloads]

On a sidenote you can also use maven to manage your dependencies and build process besides ivy. If you plan on using other frameworks or [other Vaadin addons](https://vaadin.com/directory) it may prove difficult to manage all these dependencies manually, so depending on your company's policies and configuration I'd ask whether they can grant access to the repositories or if at least there is an internal repository where one can add/find the necessary dependencies.

Comment: From what I understand, I have to add the jars from the zip to a Dynamic Web Project, but it seems that the Eclipse plugin includes more functionality, or am I wrong? Is there a way to include these jars with my current setup? Are there any extra benefits I get from installing the plugin rather than including the libraries?

Comment: @UrielArvizu The plugin and the libraries are 2 separate things. As per the [plugin intro](https://vaadin.com/eclipse#visual-designer), the IDE plugin offers a few friendly features such as the visual editor or wizards which are not vital but a nice help in your development process. On the other hand the libraries inside the zip (also from the `lib` dir inside the zip) contain the compiled classes of the Vaadin framework and its additional dependencies, necessary for the development of your application. They will also have to be shipped with your finished application, while the plugin won't.

Comment: so minus the wizards and editor, I'll be working with a normal Dynamic Web Project then?

Comment: @UrielArvizu In short yes, but it depends on your needs and requirements ([here's a short intro to Vaadin & Eclipse but using the IDE plugin as well](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KsvvF1zgMQM)). Anyhow, I'd recommend reading at least the introductory section of the [Vaadin book](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/preface.html) before starting to actually develop your application.

Comment: well it's too bad we don't get to use the plugin, seemed like a small time saver, we'll have to use the libraries only then

Comment: @UrielArvizu what I have been trying to explain is that you the libraries are mandatory for the development while the plugin is not, but it can be very useful. If you want an analogy the libraries are the wheels of the bike, and the plugin is a fender. You can not ride the bike without the wheels, but you can do without the fender. However the fender will be very useful when it starts to rain :-) Bottom line is you can use both.